# sonata product Bundle fallo en mapeo

Tags: doctrine

Estoy instalando Sonata Ecommerce. Después de bastantes errores, he llegado a tener este que no consigo solucionar:

```
[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Application\Sonata\ProductBundle\Entity\ProductCollection' mapping is invalid:
* The association Application\Sonata\ProductBundle\Entity\ProductCollection#collection refers to the inverse side field Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Collection#productCollection which does not exist.
```

Siguiendo la documentación en https://sonata-project.org/bundles/ecommerce/master/doc/reference/bundles/product.html#architecture, en la configuracion de sonata_product tengo:

```
sonata_product:
    products:
        # Prototype
        app.product:
            provider:             app.product.type  # Required
            manager:              app.product.manager  # Required
            variations:
                fields:           [] # Required
    class:
        product:              Application\Sonata\ProductBundle\Entity\Product
        package:              Application\Sonata\ProductBundle\Entity\Package
        product_category:     Application\Sonata\ProductBundle\Entity\ProductCategory
        product_collection:   Application\Sonata\ProductBundle\Entity\ProductCollection
        category:             Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category
        collection:           Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Collection
        delivery:             Application\Sonata\ProductBundle\Entity\Delivery
        gallery:              Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
```

`app.product` es un producto que he creado con el comando `sonata:product:generate`.

Entiendo que falta definir en la entidad `ClassificationBundle:Collection` una relación inversa sobre `ProductBundle:ProductCollection`. Pero no encuentro en la documentación algún ejemplo sobre que tipo de relación. He probado `many-to-one` y `one-to-many`, pero sigue dándome el mismo fallo...

Answer (score 0):

Conseguido: Al final es una one-to-many. Lo he sacado por prueba/error (no he encontrado en internet nada referido a ello. Debi equivocarme en alguno de los intentos anteriores. Dejo aqui la solución por si alguien la necesita.

He añadido la linea

`<one-to-many field="productCollection" mapped-by="collection" target-entity="Application\Sonata\ProductBundle\Entity\ProductCollection"/>`

El archivo una vez editado queda asi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <!--
         This file has been generated by the EasyExtends bundle ( https://sonata-project.org/easy-extends )

         References :
            xsd                  : https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/doctrine-mapping.xsd
            xml mapping          : http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/xml-mapping/en
            association mapping  : http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/reference/association-mapping/en
    -->
    <entity
        name="Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Collection"
        table="classification__collection"
        repository-class="Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository">

        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>
        <one-to-many field="productCollection" mapped-by="collection" target-entity="Application\Sonata\ProductBundle\Entity\ProductCollection"/>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```